# What's wrong with my OSDB hash algorithm?

Tags: c#, algorithm, hash, uwp, subtitle

I'm trying to write a c# algorithm to get a hash from an online video file to search for subtitles on (https://trac.opensubtitles.org/projects/opensubtitles/wiki/HashSourceCodes)

My idea is that the algorithm is fed a url to a video file, and returns the hash. Simple. Problem is, I'm not getting the right value back. According to the page I've linked to, [this file](http://www.opensubtitles.org/addons/avi/breakdance.avi) should return `8e245d9679d31e12`, but I'm getting `00c4fcb4aa6f763e`. Here is my C#:

```
public static async Task<byte[]> ComputeMovieHash(string filename)
{
    long filesize = 0;

    //Get File Size
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(filename);
    req.Method = "HEAD";
    var resp = await req.GetResponseAsync();
    filesize = resp.ContentLength;
    long lhash = filesize;

    //Get first 64K bytes
    byte[] firstbytes = new byte[0];
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Range", "bytes=0-65536");
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(filename))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("getting first bytes (bytes=0-65536)");
            firstbytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        }
    }
    lhash += BitConverter.ToInt64(firstbytes, 0);

    //Get last 64K bytes
    byte[] lastbytes = new byte[0];
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Range", "bytes=" + (filesize - 65536) + "-" + filesize);
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(filename))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("getting last bytes (" + "bytes=" + (filesize - 65536) + "-" + filesize + ")");
            lastbytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        }
    }
    lhash += BitConverter.ToInt64(lastbytes, 0);

    //Return result
    byte[] result = BitConverter.GetBytes(lhash);
    Array.Reverse(result);
    Debug.WriteLine("RESULT=" + ToHexadecimal(result));
    return result;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?? I've compared it to the code given by opensubtitles.org, and it seems like it should have the same outcome :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several errors in your code:

1. Range `bytes=0-65536` will return you 6553**7** bytes, which is one byte too much.
2. You do not calculate 64 bit checksum, because  `BitConverter.ToInt64(firstbytes, 0)` takes first 8 bytes and converts them to number, the rest 65536-8 bytes are completely ignored.

Fixed version should be something like this:

```
public static async Task<byte[]> ComputeMovieHash(string filename) {
    long filesize = 0;

    //Get File Size
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(filename);
    req.Method = "HEAD";
    var resp = await req.GetResponseAsync();
    filesize = resp.ContentLength;
    long lhash = filesize;

    //Get first 64K bytes
    byte[] firstbytes;
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Range", "bytes=0-65535");
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(filename)) {
            Debug.WriteLine("getting first bytes (bytes=0-65535)");
            firstbytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < firstbytes.Length; i += sizeof (long)) {
        lhash += BitConverter.ToInt64(firstbytes, i);
    }

    //Get last 64K bytes
    byte[] lastbytes;
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Range", "bytes=" + Math.Max(filesize - 65536, 0) + "-" + filesize);
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(filename)) {
            Debug.WriteLine("getting last bytes (" + "bytes=" + (filesize - 65536) + "-" + filesize + ")");
            lastbytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < lastbytes.Length; i += sizeof (long)) {
        lhash += BitConverter.ToInt64(lastbytes, i);
    }

    //Return result
    byte[] result = BitConverter.GetBytes(lhash);
    Array.Reverse(result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @user2950509 also ensure (test) that it works correctly with files with sizes less than 64KB.